# How to set Email Service Address on Email to case routing addresses

Tags: email2case

I need to create case from incoming emails. I have email to case already setup in my org. It says routing is verified, but i do not see any value in Email Service Address. How do i test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard Email-to-Case or Email Service (Apex class that `implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler`)?

If you're talking about the standard E2C, you should see the "email service address" right there in the config? If there's nothing shown try making new record. It should work without problems, maybe you'll need to contact support.

I've just created one without any hiccups. Not terribly friendly but you'll forward to this address from some nicer-looking address anyway.

[image]